# Error using ParallelMap to evaluate NIntegrate of numerical derivative ND

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, parallelization

I want to evaluate a numerical integration in which the integrand is constructed out of a function `f` and its derivative  `f'`.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

f[x11_?NumericQ, y11_?NumericQ, G11_?NumericQ, vc11_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{x = x11, y = y11, G = G11, vc = vc11}, 
   z /. Solve[(z - vc y) (z^2 - v2^2 (x^2 + y^2)) (z^2 - 
           v1^2 (x^2 + y^2)) - G z (z^2 - v1^2 y^2 - v2^2 x^2) y^2 == 
       0, z][[4]]];

fp[x11_?NumericQ, y11_?NumericQ, G11_?NumericQ, vc11_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{x = x11, y = y11, G = G11, vc = vc11}, 
   ND[f[x, y0, G, vc], y0, y]];

Int[m_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ, 
   vc_?NumericQ] := (1/
    m^2) (NIntegrate[(( 
          x Exp[f[x, y, G, vc]/m] f[x, y, G, vc]^2 fp[x, y, G, 
            vc]^2)/(Exp[f[x, y, G, vc]/m] - 1)^2) HeavisideTheta[
        y] - ((x Exp[f[x, y, G, vc]/m] f[x, y, G, vc]^2 fp[x, y, G, 
            vc]^2)/(Exp[f[x, y, G, vc]/m] - 
           1)^2) HeavisideTheta[-y], {x, 0, xlim}, {y, -ylim, ylim}, MinRecursion -> 15,
 MaxRecursion -> 20, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]);

vc = 300.;
v1 = 2.1;
v2 = 4.6;
G = 10^-7;
xlim = 100.;
ylim = 100.;

ParallelMap[Int[#, G, vc] &, Range[200, 300, 100]]
```

but it gives the following message

```
NIntegrate::inumr :  The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,100.},{-100.,100.}}.
```

when I run the code `Int[200, G, vc]` without using parallelMap it works and gives some result.
I will be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: I don't get an error, but I get a `{0., 0.}`, which is probably incorrect and may be caused by some missing definitions on the parallel kernels.

Comment: I modified the code, now it gives the error. Right, that's what I am thinking too. It is related to the using of parallelmap.